# RecyclerView with wrap_content is not animating well

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

When I have my RecyclerView height as `wrap_content`, as below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The result as below.

[image]

The is because the resize happens before the animation.

It is described more clearly in
https://medium.com/@elye.project/recyclerview-supported-wrap-content-not-quite-f04a942ce624#.n7xivnrdr

Is there a way to force it to animate first then only resize?

Comment: Why should you use wrap_content? If you have got more items, they will get out of the screen. To solve this, you should wrap it with a ScrollView which is wrong

Comment: I agree with you @ fillobotto, that there are ways working around without need wrap_content for some scenario. Nonetheless, imagine if this is supported and overcome the animation limitation, designing something with header and footer for the recyclerview doesn't need to have more complex adapter of getItemViewType(...) purely for that.

Comment: Google is plenty of codes that let you code it from scratches

Comment: did you find a solution? I see the one post here that may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243398/animatelayoutchanges-doesnt-work-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few years after, but hopefully this will help others facing the same issue.

A workaround for this situation that does not involve manipulating animations directly is to set `android:clipChildren="false"` to the parent of the RecyclerView and `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the RecyclerView.

This will allow the items that are sliding from outside of the RecyclerView to stay visible while the RecyclerView height is already resizing.

Note: This depends on the layout parent of the RecyclerView to be `match_parent`, if it isn't then the `android:clipChildren="false"` attribute must also be added to the subsequent parent(s) until the one that has the height set to `match_parent`, otherwise each one of those will behave exactly like the RecyclerView itself and hide the items animating from outside its available height.